# ggplotting multiple variables in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, finance

I have the following dataframe, which I would like to illustrate in a ggplot in R:

```
df <- structure(list(Tenors = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("12M", "1M", "1W", "3M", "6M"), class = "factor"), 
    Average = c(93.9426, 97.6231, 100.0376, 108.7951, 127.6704, 
    93.9426, 97.6231, 100.0376, 108.7951, 127.6704, 93.9426, 
    97.6231, 100.0376, 108.7951, 127.6704, 93.9426, 97.6231, 
    100.0376, 108.7951, 127.6704, 93.9426, 97.6231, 100.0376, 
    108.7951, 127.6704, 93.9426, 97.6231, 100.0376, 108.7951, 
    127.6704, 93.9426, 97.6231, 100.0376, 108.7951, 127.6704, 
    93.9426, 97.6231, 100.0376, 108.7951, 127.6704, 93.9426, 
    97.6231, 100.0376, 108.7951, 127.6704, 93.9426, 97.6231, 
    100.0376, 108.7951, 127.6704, 93.9426, 97.6231, 100.0376, 
    108.7951, 127.6704, 93.9426, 97.6231, 100.0376, 108.7951, 
    127.6704, 93.9426, 97.6231, 100.0376, 108.7951, 127.6704, 
    93.9426, 97.6231, 100.0376, 108.7951, 127.6704, 93.9426, 
    97.6231, 100.0376, 108.7951, 127.6704, 93.9426, 97.6231, 
    100.0376, 108.7951, 127.6704, 93.9426, 97.6231, 100.0376, 
    108.7951, 127.6704, 93.9426, 97.6231, 100.0376, 108.7951, 
    127.6704), Pairs = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("audusd", "euraud", "eurchf", 
    "eurgbp", "eurjpy", "eurnok", "eurtry", "eurusd", "gbpusd", 
    "nzdusd", "usdcad", "usdchf", "usddkk", "usdhkd", "usdjpy", 
    "usdnok", "usdsek", "usdzar"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Tenors", 
"Average", "Pairs"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90"
))
```

... if i run str(df) i get that my Tenors and Pairs are factors and Average is numeric.

when I run the following:

```
ggplot(seperate, aes(x=seperate$Tenors,y = seperate$Average, colour = Pairs,group=2)) + 
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  xlab("Tenor")+
  ylab("Average")+
  ylim(c(50,150))
```

.. I only receive the first 5 rows of my df as in

[image]

... what am I doing wrong ??

Best, ph

Comment: your points are exactly the same; all the lines are on top of each otther

Comment: Do not use `$` within `aes`. Gpplot2 looks for the variables in the declared data.frame. `ggplot(seperate, aes(x=Tenors,y = Average, colour = Pairs))`

Comment: Thanks MLavoie & Roland

Comment: Instead of group=2, do group=Pairs.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at this. Basically your data all lies on top of each other, makes it hard to see. So I added some noise with jitter. Also if you use something like `seperate$Tenors` inside of an `aes()` it confuses ggplot2 since it gets a vector instead of a reference to a data frame and cannot do as much with the data.

Note there is one odd pair **"eurusd"** - this gets mapped to a "blank" country.

So using your data I used this:

```
set.seed(1234)
# Arrange the "Tenors" factor correctly
df$Tenors <- factor(df$Tenors,levels=c("1W","1M","3M","6M","12M"))

# Get a numerical valued tenor for geom_line (it seemingly doesn't like factors)
df$NTenors <- as.numeric(df$Tenors)

# jitter the values so they don't all overwrite each other
df$Average <- jitter(df$Average,2)

df$cur <- ifelse(grepl("usd",df$Pairs),"usd","eur")

# extract country from pairs
df$country <- gsub("usd","",df$Pairs) # gsub is not vectorized dammit
df$country <- gsub("eur","",df$country)

seperate <- df

ggplot(seperate, aes(x=Tenors,y=Average, color=country)) +       
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(x=NTenors))+
  facet_grid(.~cur)+
  xlab("Tenor")+
  ylab("Average")+
  ylim(c(90,130))
```

yielding this:

[image]

Comment: Added country extraction as that is probably what you want.

Comment: Is this not what you want?